# Filling an array with integer then using trial division find prime numbers less than N

Tags: c++, division, trial

This function is supposed to take in three parameters and find the prime numbers less than the NUM inputed using trial division

```
void trialDivision(int prime[], const int NUM, const int SIZE) {
int j = NUM;
for (int i = 0; i < NUM; i++) {
    prime[i] = 1;
}

for (int i = 2; i <= sqrt(NUM); i++, j++) {
    put numbers less than n into array
}
```

Then do trial division to find prime numbers.

I am having a problem figuring out how to put numbers less than sqrt(NUM) into a function.

Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to implement Sieve of Eratosthenes? Google it and you'll find many examples. Or start with Wikipedia.

Answer (score 0):

First, you're going to want to create a loop that goes from `i=2` to `i<NUM`. This is to check every positive integer greater than 1 up to NUM-1 for primeness. It would look something like this:

```
for (int i=2;i<NUM;i++)
{
    // prime checking
}
```

Now for the actual prime checking. Let's put this in a function. This is where you would use `sqrt()` to define the upper bound of the loop. Once again we start our loop at `j=2` because all numbers are divisible by 1, so there's no need to include that.

```
bool isPrime(int i)
{
    for (int j=2;j<sqrt(i);j++)
    {
         if (i%j==0)
         {
              return false;
         }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Basically, if the loop terminates, then we have not found any factors of `i` between `2` and `sqrt(i)`, so it is prime.

Now simply call this function in your first loop.

```
for (int i=2;i<NUM;i++)
{
     if (isPrime(i))
     {
         prime[i] = 1; // or whatever you want to use to represent a prime. If you use 1, it's best if you initiate the array with 0's
     }
}
```

If you wanted just a list of primes, then `std::vector<int>` would be a better choice for storing your results.